# Does this analysis make sense and can references to similar work be provided?

Tags: regression, prediction, generalized-estimating-equations, marginal-effect, marginal-model

I posted this question previously here, but did not receive any answers.  I'm resurrecting this question in hopes that someone might be able to provide some feedback and/or references.  Hopefully this is okay.

I have a logistic regression model that I've built using GEE that predicts that probability of mortality given a rather extensive set of covariates. I wanted to write here as a sanity check of sorts to make sure that what I'm doing seems sensible and to get some clarification on how to go about obtaining confidence intervals for this analysis. Allow me to explain:

The purpose of the study is to examine the relationship between a continuous intervention variable (which is a percentage in the range of 0 to 100%) on mortality while controlling for a number of other covariates. I build a model in GEE due to the data having some dependencies and repeated patient visits. After building the model, I made predictions on the datasets, holding all the variables in my model constant with the exception of the intervention, which I initially set fixed at 0% (and later to 10%, 20%, . . 100%) for every patient in the dataset. This gave me predictions of mortality for each individual. Now, within each of four risk categories (a categorical variable that appears in the model), I obtained the mean predicted mortality rate, the mean predicted upper 95% confidence interval and the mean predicted lower 95% confidence interval. So in the end, I have four risk categories, each with a mean predicted mortality and mean 95% upper and lower confidence bounds. This processed was repeated once for each 10% increment of my intervention variable. My intention was to essentially look at the all the patient characteristics and form a counterfactual where the only thing I change is the intervention, and made predictions to see, hypothetically, what could we expect if, all else being constant, the intervention had actually been 10% (or 20%, 30%, etc.) instead of what was actually observed.

So my questions are: (1) Does this sound like a sound/reasonable approach and if so (2) Is it appropriate to simply take the mean of the individual 95% upper and lower confidence intervals to find confidence intervals for each level of categorical risk factor and intervention percentage? If not, how else can I go about this, without having to separately tabulate the confidence intervals for very specific linear combinations of an extensive list of predictors? Essentially, I'm trying to avoid having to say something like, for those with high oxygen saturation levels, having never experienced cancer before, who were previously admitted for the same condition, and high cancer risk, the confidence interval is (x, y). In other words, I'd like to be able to just say something about the the intervention in each of the groups, across all patients reflective of their other current clinical characteristics en masse.

Comment: Please don't re-post an unanswered question.  Visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers for information on what to do instead.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber.  Sorry about that.  I looked for this exact info.  Much appreciated.